# How to store a function object without resorting to std::function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I am trying to make a generic container that would hold objects and their position:

```
class Vector;

template <typename T>
class Container 
{
public:
    void insert(const T& t)
    {
        insertAtPosition(t.getPosition() ,t);
    }
private:
    void insertAtPosition(const Vector& v, const T& t);
    ...
} ;
```

But what if the users' object position getter is not called `getPosition`?

**How can I make this container generic with respect to the way in which the container internally obtains the position of an item?**

So far, I have considered 3 approaches, none of them ideal:

1. Add a `std::function<const Vector& (const T& t)>` member to the `Container`.

This is a clean C++ solution, but this function is going to be called very very often and it may result in noticeable performance decrease.

2. Add a functor object to the container:

   ```
   class Vector;

   template <typename T, typename TGetPosition>
   class Container 
   {
   public:
        Container(TGetPosition getPosition): getPosition_(getPosition){}

        void insert(const T& t)
        {
            insertAtPosition(getPosition_(t) ,t);
        }
   private:
        void insertAtPosition(const Vector& v, const T& t);
        TGetPosition getPosition_;
   } ;
   ```

I can use the [object generator idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Object_Generator) to make it possible to use lambdas:

```
template <typename T, typename TGetPosition>
Container<T, TGetPosition> makeContainer(TGetPosition getter)
{
    return Container<T, TGetPosition>(getter);
}

...

auto container = makeSimpleContainer<Widget>([](const Widget& w)
    {
        return w.tellMeWhereYourPositionMightBe();
    });
```

There would be no performance overhead, but it would be impossible to get the type of such a container in certain contexts. For example, you could not create a class that would take such a container as a parameter, since `decltype` would not work, because lambdas cannot be used in unevaluated contexts.

3. Use `#define GETTER getPosition` and the user would just change `getPosition` to whatever he likes. There are so many things wrong with this approach that I don't even know where to start.

Please, is there some other way to do this? Did I miss anything. Any guidance is most welcome!

EDIT:

Regarding solution 2: I have no idea how could we get a the type of a container created with a lambda function. One way would be:

```
using TContainer = decltype(makeSimpleContainer<Widget>([](const Widget& w)
    {
        return w.tellMeWhereYourPositionMightBe();
    });)
```

But this doesn't work, because lambdas cannot be used in unevaluated contexts.

Comment: Are you saying that `t.getPosition()` returns a vector?

Comment: Can you give an example of the `decltype` problem you describe, as it relates to your problem?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, exactly. T has an implicit interface.

Comment: What about making the accessor a template parameter: `template <typename T, const Vector& (T::*Get)() const> class Container;`

Comment: why would there be a **performance** overhead if you stored the lambda via a `std::function` compared to storing it as a  `TGetPosition` class member? did you benchmark this?

Comment: @KerrekSB, Yes, this is a good idea!

Comment: @m.s. Indeed, I have no evidence of this, just a suspicion. However I wanted to see all possible approaches beforehand.

Comment: For solution 2, why not use `decltype` on the `auto container` variable instead of using `decltype` on the `makeSimpleContainer` call?

Comment: @m.s `std::function` uses virtual dispatch because it can hold a variety of unrelated things. This inhibits optimization because the compiler cannot inline the `operator()`. My suggestion is to follow the pattern of `std::unique_ptr` and have a traits class. Then you would say `container_traits<Widget>::getPosition(w)`, and the class would be `Container<Widget>`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes! I think that this is the best idea sofar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasonably usable option would be to expect the context to have `position_for()`:

```
template <class T> struct Container {
    size_t insert(T const& x) {
        insertAtPosition(position_for(x), x);
    }
};

Vector const& position_for(const Widget& w) {
    return ...;
}

Container<Widget> c;
c.insert(Widget());
```

...but designs where the container generates key from the business object usually do not fly well, as to lookup the object one would need to do a dummy one, which may be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your second solution will work even if you need to make a class holding a container:

```
template <typename Container>
struct SomeClass {
    SomeClass(const Container &container) : container(container) { }
    Container container;
};


int main()
{
    auto container = makeSimpleContainer<Widget>([](const Widget& w)
        {
            return w.tellMeWhereYourPositionMightBe();
        });
    SomeClass<decltype(container)> test(container);
}
```